# MigraDoc table with rounded corners

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

How can I set rounded corners for a table? I'm using c# and MigraDoc.

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table myTable = section.AddTable();
myTable.Borders.Visible = true;
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Column myColumn = myTable.AddColumn();
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Row myRow = myTable.AddRow();
myRow[0].AddParagraph("Some text");
```

Answer (score 1):

PdfSharp can do it. Not sure about MigraDoc.

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI/PdfSharp/XGraphicsPath/M/AddRoundedRectangle

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-GDI/PdfSharp/XGraphics/M/DrawRoundedRectangle

Comment: Could you please update here, If someone has achieved this in Migradoc.

Answer (score 1):

MigraDoc table cells have a `RoundedCorner` property.
I do not have time now to create a fully functional sample, but AIUI you must add dummy rows at the top and at the bottom as well as dummy columns at the left and at the right to make room for the rounded corners. You have to set cell shading to see the effect of the rounded corners. And most likely those rounded corners will work with PDF only, not with RTF.

Code snippet that shows how to use the properties:

```
public static void SetRoundedCorners(Table table)
{
    int rowCount = table.Rows.Count;
    int colCount = table.Columns.Count;

    if (rowCount < 2 || colCount < 2)
        return;

    table.Rows[0].Cells[0].RoundedCorner = RoundedCorner.TopLeft;
    table.Rows[0].Cells[colCount - 1].RoundedCorner =  RoundedCorner.TopRight;
    table.Rows[rowCount - 1].Cells[colCount - 1].RoundedCorner =  RoundedCorner.BottomRight;
    table.Rows[rowCount - 1].Cells[0].RoundedCorner =  RoundedCorner.BottomLeft;
}
```